# ipad: "Recents" in safari fileupload offers outdated document version

Tags: macos, ipad, finder, safari, ipados

When selecting `recent` in safari fileupload on ipad, the version of the files offered there tend to be not the current version of the file.

In more details:

- In goodnotes5, I export the current document as pdf: I `save to files`, choose the `downloads` folder and click `save`. This creates e.g. `a.pdf`.
- I continue editing and then do all the above again. As the file already exists, I am asked whether to `replace` or `keep both`.   I choose `replace`.
- Checking the `files` app, in `on my ipad` and the folder `downloads`, I now see two versions of this file (with same filename, but different datestamps).
- I now try to upload the file: I open safari, go to a webpage with a fileupload form, and select `add files` and then `browse`. I now have a choice between `recents` and `browse`.  `recents` shows me only the first (outdated) version of the file `a.pdf`, and `browse` only shows the second (current) version. (And if I select `a.pdf` via `recent`, then it actually uploads to outdated version.)
- A few minutes later, also `recents` will show the newer (current) version.

This is extremely annoying for my workflow. A few potential sulotions come to my mind:

Questions:

- Is there a fix or this bug? If not:
- Is it possible to automatically / programatically refresh the `recent` list?
- Is it possible to automatically / programatically delete all entries of the download folder?
- Is it possible to change the download folder settings so that only the most recent version of any document is stored?
- Or maybe instead of saving to a file, I could "send to" e.g. pythonista and then save into a suitable folder where the filename is appended with some unique tag?

(I am aware that I could just choose a unique filenam whenever exporting the pdf, but I would like a solution with as little manual input as possible.)

btw, this is ios 13.1.3 and safari "Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15"